# Queue data publish/duplicate

Tags: duplicates, compare, ibm-mq, mq

I am using IBM webSphere MQ 7.5 server as queue manager for my applications.
Already I am receiving data through single queue.

On the other hand there are 3  applications that want to process data.
I have 3 solutions to duplicate/distribute data between them.

1. Use broker to duplicate 1 to 3 queue - I don't have broker so it is not accessible for me.
2. Write an application to get from queue and put them in other 3 queues on same machine
3. Define publish/subscribe definitions to publish input queue to 3 queues on same machine.

I want to know which methods (2 & 3) is preferred and have higher performance and acceptable operational management effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the description I would say that going PubSub would achieve the goal; try to thinking in pure PubSub terms rather than thinking about the queues. i.e. You have an application that publishes to a topic with then 3 applications each having their own subscription to get copies of the message.

You then have the flexibility to define durable/nondurable subscriptons for example.

Answer (score 0):

For option # 2, there are (at least) 2 solutions available:

1. There is an open source application called [MMX](http://www.capitalware.com/mmx_overview.html) (Message Multiplexer).  It will do exactly what you describe.  The only issue is that you will need to manage the application.  i.e. If you stop the queue manager then the application will need to be manually restarted.
2. There is a commercial solution called [MQ Message Replication](http://www.capitalware.com/mqmr_overview.html).  It is an API Exit that runs within the queue manager and does exactly what you want.  Note: There is nothing external to manage as it runs within the queue manager.

Comment: You can use a service object to start external applications when the queue manager starts: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.adm.doc/q020970_.htm?lang=en

Answer (score -1):

I think there is another solution, with MQ only, to define a Namelist which will mirror queue1 to queue2 and queue3
Should be defined like: Source, Destination, QueueManager.

Hope it is useful.

Biruk.